# How to add more languages docs to Devhelp? (Java etc)

Tags: programming, development

I was wondering if there is a way to add more languages (such as Java, C, C++ etc) to Devhelp.

I know that there is a software named zeal, but Dev help seems to be more mature.

By the way, I'm on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) provides an offline version of their site in devhelp form. They have it in a ppa here:
https://launchpad.net/~p12/+archive/ppa

it should install by way of:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:p12/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cppreference-doc-en
```

For 14.04 You have to append -html which makes it

```
sudo apt-get install cppreference-doc-en-html
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be supported in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: The package is now available at Ubuntu's default repositories (my release is Focal Fossa).